# Is Kubenetes related software automatically installed on Ubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, hacking, kubernetes

I have since yesterday noticed that the top command has been showing kubelet, kube-apiserver, kube-controller and other Kubernetes related processes running on my computer. This is alarming me and making me wonder why and what if I have been pwnd.

I have Lubuntu installed for over 2 years now. I have upgraded to 18.04 about 4 months ago. I have been using Linux Containers on this distro since it was installed.

I never use docker and barely know much about Kubernetes and don't know why these processes are running on my computer.

I also haven't seen that these software are automatically installed in Ubuntu.

So I guess my question is should these processes be on my computer if I haven't installed anything related to Kubernetes?

Also can they used for hacking purposes?

Comment: The easiest thing to do, in cases like this, is to install `aptitude` and ask `aptitude why kubelet` (and `aptitude why kubeadm` and `aptitude why kubectl`). This will tell you why these packages are needed, i.e., which other packages depend on them. Drill down until you are convinced that they are necessary, or if you aren't, `apt remove` them.

Comment: @Jos - oddly, aptitude replies that these package names do not exist all while top shows them running. I've tried using sudo as well.

Comment: You may have installed a `snap` package. Please do `snap find kubeadm`.

Comment: That's it. It was snap. I was able to find but when I do sudo snap (logs or disable or remove) kubelet, it says `snap "kubelet" is not installed`. Same for the other kube related names.

Comment: `sudo snap list` shows only `core 16.2.37.4` and `microk8s v1.140`. Looking this microk8s proves that this is a kubernetes tool. @Jos - Thanks for the guidance. Still no sure why this is here and why it is running commands but I will uninstall and see what happens...

Comment: Taking a hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884322/how-to-remove-kubectl-from-ubuntu-16-04-lts), did you download the Google Cloud SDK?

Comment: No. I've never had interest in Kubernetes enough to install or tinker with. I'd like to in the future but that moment hasn't crossed yet... I also haven't used docker yet as I still am in a phase of interest in Linux Containers. I looked at rckt for a while but looks like that project has been stalled.

Comment: Do you have something like `kubernetes.list` inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?

Comment: No. I also check my latest containers and nothing of the sort in those either.